# jQuery SlideDown jumps in Bootstrap 3 row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slidedown

I'm trying to make a div slide down (animating visible) with jquery. The animation isn't smooth and jumps in the end.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="items">
      <li class="item col-sm-4">as</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">as</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="more-items">
      <li class="item col-sm-4">as</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
    </ul>
  </div
  <div class="row">
    <a id="show-more-btn" class="show-more-items">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      <span class="text">Vis flere</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's a well known problem and is caused by jquery not knowing the height of the element to animate. So I made a function on document "ready" to calculate height of sliding element before hiding.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.more-items').css('height',function(i,h){
    alert(h);  
    $(this).hide();
      return h;
  });

  $("#show-more-btn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".more-items").slideDown();
  });

});
```

This works perfectly but when element is inside a BS3 grid row the height is always 0px...

Why is this and how can I make sure that the element has a height inside the BS grid?

I'm not able to use the BS "collapse()" function because I can't load the BS js-file on the site I'm working on.

**EXAMPLE** *Drag the window wide enough to see the 3 columns.*
https://jsfiddle.net/vn1z6z9L/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found the solution! If I put col-sm-12 on the `<ul>` it gets a height. I don't even need to calculate it before hiding the .more-items list :-)

Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vn1z6z9L/3/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="items col-sm-12">
      <li class="item col-sm-4">asf</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">dd</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">ssddf</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">as</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">as</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="more-items col-sm-12">
      <li class="item col-sm-4">as</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">as</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
      <li class="item col-sm-4">sdf</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I made some changes
https://jsfiddle.net/vn1z6z9L/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#show-more-btn").on("click", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(".more-items").slideToggle();
});   

});
```

And

```
.more-items{
 display:none;
 }
```

> The slideToggle() method toggles between slideUp() and slideDown() for the selected elements.
>
> This method checks the selected elements for visibility.
>
> slideDown() is run if an element is hidden. slideUp() is run if an
>   element is visible - This creates a toggle effect.
>
> Thus you don't need to use the BS collapse .

Comment: I don't need slideToggle(), I only need slideDown. In your example slideDown still jumps!!

Comment: for the sake of knowledge ,what is it that you are trying to achieve, what do mean by slideDown jump ?

Comment: If you expand the window in your jsfiddle you will see the list splitting up in three columns. This is the Bootstrap grid. Then you click the Show More button to make the list slide down. In the very end of the slide the animation isn't smooth. It goes a little too far down and jumps back in place. That is what I mean!